# How to make user input statements more generalizable？

Tags: python-3.x, input

When the user using this input, that have to write exactly what it is in the stack, for example "spade" won't work because stack[i].type is "Spade". So I want to ask if there is a way to make the program work either the user input S for spade and some other options.

```
`def selectCard():
    CardTypeSelected = input("Enter the type of the Card you want to select:")
    CardNumberSelected = input("Enter the number of the Card you want to select:")
    for i in range(len.stack):
        if stack[i].type == CardTypeSelected and stack[i].number == CardNumberSelected:
            useCard(CardTypeSelected, CardNumberSelected)`
```

Comment: pick a convention for `stack[i].type` for example all upperclass then `stack[i].type == CardTypeSelected.upper()`

Comment: If i change add an .upper() after the variable, will that means no matter what the user input as long the letter is write this will return true? for example if the user input "sPadE"

Comment: Yes, that should work